# clj-pdf: Error adding image in a table

Tags: pdf, clojure

I'm using the clj-pdf library for Clojure to create pdf that contain charts.  I'm making the charts using the Incanter library and converting the images to byte arrays. Then I'm attempting to use clj-pdf to make a pdf that has 4 charts, one in each corner.  When I do this I get an error IllegalArgumentException Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Keyword  clojure.lang.RT.seqFrom (RT.java:505)
I can successfully add the images outside of a table but the formatting sucks, one image per line.  Anyone how to fix this?

Heres the line of code I'm trying:

```
(pdf [{} [:table {} [:cell [:image {} plot1-bytearr]
         [:image {} plot2-bytearr]]]] "test.pdf")
```

***EDIT***
Link to trace: http://pastebin.com/b7DEnjXY
Link to workable (hopefully) example: http://pastebin.com/fPvjFFbi

Comment: Can you provide more code and/or the full stacktrace (in a gist or pastebin as Clojure stacks tend to be huge)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `:table` needs to be specified in rows, e.g.

```
(pdf [{} [:table row1 
                 row2
                 row3]] 
     "test.pdf")
```

Rows need to be sequences.

```
(pdf [{} [:table ["11" "12" "13"]
                 ["21" "22" "23"]]] "test.pdf")
```

You have placed two images in one cell, but doing

```
(pdf [{} [:table [[:cell "11" "12" "13"]]
                 ["21" "22" "23"]]] "test.pdf")
```

would omit "12" and "13" and create a table with 11, 21 and 22 in the first row and 23 as the first cell in the second row. I don't think this usage of `:cell` is supported. If you wanted to use multiple cells in one cell I would create another `:table` vector inside the `:cell` vector which is supported.

Based on your example the solution is

```
(pdf [{} [:table [[:image plot1-bytearr][:image plot2-bytearr]]]]
     "test.pdf")
```

Please note the extra brackets around the vector of `:image`s. Clj-pdf tries to read your `:cell` keyword as a sequence containing a cell for `:table`, hence the exception telling you that it's expecting a sequence.

- This won't give you 4 charts. Since you have only provided two, I guess this solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I copied my method over displaying data and didn't realize I could do without the :cell.  Works perfect